# Regex: ways to make expression shorter

Tags: regex

I have such regex:

`^([0369]|[258][0369]*[147]|([147]|[258][0369]*[258])([0369]|[0369]*[147][0369]*[258])*([258]|[147][0369]*[147]))+$`

I built it from finite automata, but expression is too long. There are a lot of repeating group of symbols, such as `[0369]`. Is there any way to create some shorter alias for this group of symbols?

Or maybe you can suggest some other ways to shorten it?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20795697/1578604)

Comment: Why is it too long? What or where is the limitation on length?

Comment: what is the intention of your regex?

Comment: @Bohemian The regex must validate that a number is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the regex is visually:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If your flavor supports recursive subpatterns, you can simplify the regex like this:

```
/^(
    (?<A>[0369]) |
    (?<B>[258])(?&A)*(?<C>[147]) |
    (
      (?&C) | (?&B)(?&A)*(?&B)
    )
    (
      (?&A) | (?&A)*(?&C)(?&A)*(?&B)
    )*
    (
      (?&B) | (?&C)(?&A)*(?&C)
    )
  )+
 $/x
```

which visually gives

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can hardly get something simpler.